# Is there a more elegant way to use linq to set attribute values?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following blurb of code, which will select all **Data** elements in my XML which have a **RatingNumericValue**, and then set the value for that data element to the contents of the RatingNumericValue.  I was wondering if this would be a good candidate for using a predicate.  Is there a better way of using linq to do this?

```
    Dim dataEls = From item In copy...<Table>...<Row>...<Cell>...<Data> Select item Where item.@RatingNumericValue IsNot Nothing
    For Each de In dataEls
        de.Value = de.@RatingNumericValue
    Next
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a better way of using linq to do this?

No. LINQ is aimed at *querying*, which doesn't include modifying objects. Likewise a *predicate* is used as a sort of matcher - again, nothing to do with setting properties.

While you could use `List<T>.ForEach`, I would advise against it - it's needlessly complicated compared with the simple `foreach` loop you've already got.

Theoretically you could write a predicate which set a property and then always returned true - then you'd need to call `Count()` or something on the result to force the predicate to be executed against every item. I **strongly** advise against this though. Predicates which mutate the data they're called on are horrible things.

Comment: I agree that predicates mutating data is bad style (misuse of API, side effects), but *horrible things* are strong words.  Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `List<T>1 extension method ForEach to remove the explicit loop.  However, that requires that you convert your`IEnumerable`to a`List`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx

http://craigwatson1962.com/2010/10/08/using-the-foreach-method/

Comment: `ForEach` is actually a method on `List<T>` and does not require LINQ.